# Sequelize findAll with association and foreign key

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize to model a mySql-database schema in my node-application. Let's say I have 3 table: Project, User and Role.

It's a "Many to Many" association between Project and User through "Project_User" where is defined the role of a user for a project.

**Project Model :**

```
var Project = sequelize.define('Project', {
    name:{type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true}
},
classMethods: {
   associate: function(models) {
       Project.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: 'Project_User', as: 'users'});
   }
}
// Methods...
);
```

**User Model :**

```
var User= sequelize.define('User', {
    name:{type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true}
},
classMethods: {
   associate: function(models) {
       User.belongsToMany(models.Project, { through: 'Project_User', as: 'projects'});
   }
}
// Methods...
);
```

And here is the association table **Project_User Model** :

```
var Project_User = sequelize.define('Project_User', {
    role:
    {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: 'Role',
        referencesKey: 'id'
    }
},{
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
            Project_User.belongsTo(models.Role, {foreignKey: 'role'});
        }
    }
});
```

Now, I want to find all project, with their users and their role. So I've used findAll with the "include" parameters like below:

```
models.Projects.findAll({
    include:[
             {
                 model: models.User, 
                 as:'users',
                 through: {attributes: ['role'], as: 'role'}
             }]
}).then(function(result) {
     // ...
});
```

This works great but I only have the roleId associated to the user. I wasn't be able to link this "roleId" with the role table to get the other attributes like role name...

Here is the JSON I've got :

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Project name",
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "User name",
            "role": {
                "role": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

But I would like to have something like that :

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Project name",
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "User name",
            "role": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Role name",
                "description": "Some info...",
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I've tried many things to realize this association, even successive includes but it was unsuccessful. What is needed in the findAll options to get this JSON result ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `User` model is linked to the `Role` model, something like this should work:

```
models.Projects.findAll({
    include:[
             {
                 model: models.User, 
                 as:'users',
                 through: {attributes: []},
                 include: [models.Role]
             }] }).then(function(result) {
     // ... });
```

Comment: Thanks to you reply but I've already try and it doesn't works. Indeed, I've got an error like "Unknown column users.role" which makes sense because role isn't a column from users table but in project_user.

Comment: If you don't have a relation between User and Role then your only option is to model the join table (project_user) and add the relation to Role there. You can't retrieve full model data (a row of a table) without defining an association...

Comment: Yes that's what I've done. You can see my Projet_User model, with a relation to Role (roleId as foreign key). But I haven't found the correct syntax in my **findAll()** to display role data and not only the foreign key roleId for each user associated to the project.

Comment: @Raptack it would be awesome if you got a solution now and you can share it with us, I have the same problem now... thanks